# Prove that $\sin x=[1+\sin x]+[1-\cos x]$ has no solution in $x\in \Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, functions, trigonometry

> Prove that $$\sin x=[1+\sin x]+[1-\cos x]$$ has no solution for $x\in \Bbb R$ 
>   where $[x]=\lfloor x\rfloor$

$$$$I reduced the equation into $$\sin x=2+[\sin x]+[-\cos x]$$

From here, I plotted the graphs of $\sin x$ and $-\cos x$, and then plottted the graphs of $[\sin x]$ and $[-\cos x]$. Finally, I split the number line into intervals and some distinct points in/at which I added the respective values of $[\sin x]$ and $[-\cos x]$ thus showed that within those intervals/at those points, there were no values of $x$ for which the original equation was valid.

$$$$I found this method quite long and messy (I usually hate methods which involve graphs as I'm a tad slow at them) and was wondering if a shorter and nicer method exists. If so, then could someone kindly show me the method? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that $|sin(x)| \leq 1$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That struck me at first too, but I couldn't understand how to apply it here.

Comment: The right side is always an integer, while the only integer values the left side could take are -1, 0, and 1. Couldn't you just try each of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue your idea, we get 
$$\sin x-[\sin x]=2+[-\cos x].$$ 
Note that $0\leqslant \sin x-[\sin x]<1$. But, $-1\leqslant -\cos x\leqslant 1$, thus $ [-\cos x]\in\{-1,0,1\}\Rightarrow 2+[-\cos x]\in\{1,2,3\}\Rightarrow 2+[-\cos x]\geqslant 1>x-[\sin x].$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sin(x)$ is an integer.  But then $\lfloor \sin(x) \rfloor=\sin(x)$, so your equation reduces to $$\lceil \cos(x) \rceil=2$$ which is not possible.